I can't find the error in this multisort colum script
I was out on leave and a sheet that I wrote script on is mysteriously no longer working. The goal of the script is as follows:
The sheet is edited multiple times a day, as the user enters the data in the sheet, it will auto sort by date once data is entered into column 12.
Upon execution the script works. However a few minutes later I'll run it again and will receive an error. Invalid argument multiSortColumns @ Auto-Sort.gs:19
Assuming line 19 of code:  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
What am I missing?

SHEET_NAME = "AllEvents";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:AF";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 4, ascending: true},
];

function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == 12) {
    multiSortColumns();
  }
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}


This works:
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "AllEvents" && e.range.columnStart == 12) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    sh.getRange("A3:AF" + sh.getLastRow()).sort({column:4,ascending:true});
    e.source.toast('Sort complete.');
  }
}


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit @ Auto-Sort.gs:10

This is only to be executed by the onedit trigger which also supplies the event object. If you wish to run it from an intermediate function then you will have to supply the event object  yourself,

Thank you for doing this! I'd love to know more about why it wasn't running in the original script but I like the ease and simplicity of your solution.
